# Alternative code for solving pendulum equation $\ddot{\theta} + \sin{\theta} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

One MATLAB code for solving pendulum equation $\ddot{\theta} + \sin{\theta} = 0$ is:

T=100;
h=0.1; n=floor(T/h);
y0 = [1 0];

y=y0; sol=y0;
for nT = 1:2
   theta = y(1);
   y(1) = y(1) + h*y(2);
   y(2) = y(2) - h*sin(theta);
   sol = [sol;y];
end

My question is how can I write the code for an alternative algorithm:
${\theta}_{n+1} = {\theta}_{n} + h{\omega}_{n};  {\omega}_{n+1} = {\omega}_{n} - h\sin({\theta}_{n+1})$
where ${\omega} = \dot{\theta}$.

How can I define omega as the first derivate in MATLAB (without using symbolic toolbox). Or is there any other way?

I tried to write the code:

T=100; 
h=0.1; n=floor(T/h);
theta0 = [1 0];

theta = theta0; sol = theta0;
for nT = 1:n
   theta = theta + h*omega;
   omega = omega - h*sin(theta);
end

But because I have not yet defined omega, an error occur.
Help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code is almost there.  Just use

y(2)=y(2)-h*sin(y(1))

instead of

y(2)=y(2)-h*sin(theta).

No matter what method you use, you are simply going to have to provide an initial y(2) in addition to the initial y(1).  This is what is called a second order equation, and they always need initial values and initial first derivatives.

Comment: Thanks very much for the code and the explanation! I plotted the 2 algorithms and they resulted in different pictures. I guess the 2nd algorithm shows the periodic nature of the solution.

Comment: Couple of things: Your first method is a straightforward first order solver.  Your second is a "leapfrog" method. Leapfrog is always more accurate. You might see the periodic behavior in your first method if you decrease your time step by ... alot. Also, just so I don't get dinged on this, second order equations need *either* an initial value and a first derivative *or* a first value and then a value at some other position in space/time/whatever the indepedent variable is, all depending on the nature of the equation. This one needs initial value and derivative.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get lots more points if you hit the "accept" button.  :)